# Quads acting as black or white pixels

Tags: texturing, uv

[image: example screenshot]

Hello, I'm trying to figure out a way for quad mesh to act as black or white pixels. In short, I won't to be able to put UV wrap a black and white image texture on an object with this kind of mesh and have a shader that would pixelate it by making quads in mesh black or white.

The example image I achieved by manualy applying black or white (in this case yellow) material onto faces, which is obviously too tedious and rules out a potential for animated textures that I would like to achieve later on with this effect.

Is this doable?
Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want all faces to have a solid color, looked up from a single point on a texture?  The main thing is that the faces have to have 0-area UV.  The easiest way to achieve this is by using a geometry nodes modifier:

[image]

I capture the *face* UV (the average of its face-corners) and output it as a face-corner attribute.  I then look up the texture using "closest" mode rather than with linear filtering.

If I apply this modifier and then convert the attribute back into regular UV, I can see exactly what it did:

[image]

Just shrunk all the faces to 0-area.  Which you could do manually, but would be tedious, since "individual origins" pivot point sees the whole island as an individual origin.

If the issue is that the texture input isn't black and white, we can do some shader modifications:

[image]

RGB->BW will convert the color to grayscale.  Math/greater than will establish a single threshold, to convert any gray values to either black or white, depending on where we set that threshold.  If you want grayscale, use RGB->BW.  If you want black and white, you don't need that node, just the "greater than"; it will do the BW conversion implicitly.

Comment: Thanks so much, never worked with geometry nodes before so it was a bit tricky for me, but it works perfectly when set up!